# GCP billing alerts by SKU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, billing, uptime-monitoring

Is there a way to get a billing alert by SKU in GCP so I know when I am about to cross the free threshold?  The free tier for Uptime Checks in 1M/Month and I want to know when I am getting close to that tier.  I can get billing alerts by Service but cloud monitoring in general is too broad to set alerts for.

Thanks!

I have already tried alerting by service.

Comment: Billing alerts do not support API usage. You can create a metric on API usage: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring#expandable-1